# Error while validating numbers in php

Tags: php, regex

I m trying to validate only numbers in php but it is displaying error message.I want user to enter a valid mobile number,batch where only 4 numbers as to be entered. No characters should be entered.Please tell me whats the error in the code.
Here is the code

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $error = "";

    if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    } else {
    $error .= "You didn't type in your name. <br />";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
      if (!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email)){ 
      $error .= "The e-mail address you entered is not valid. <br/>";
      }
    } else {
    $error .= "You didn't type in an e-mail address. <br />";
    }
if (!empty($_POST['batch'])) {
    $batch = $_POST['batch'];
    } 
    if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $batch)) { 
      $error .= "Enter a Valid Number. <br/>";
      }

    else {
    $error .= "You didn't type batch. <br />";
    }
     if(($_POST['code']) == $_SESSION['code']) { 
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    } else { 
    $error .= "The captcha code you entered does not match. Please try again. <br />";    
    }



    if (!empty($_POST['mobile'])) {
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    } 
    if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $mobile)){ 
      $error .= "Enter A Valid Number. <br/>";
      }
    else {
    $error .= "You didn't type your Mobile Number. <br />";
    }
```

Comment: Change to `if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $batch)) {`, else the error message will be showned when every time you only enter numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{4}$/', $batch)
```

Use this if you want to validate for only 4 numbers.